# Асинхронные запросы Python

Tags: python

Пишу бота для Telegram на Python для скачивания музыки из VK YouTube. Тестируя его заметил, что он работает по принципу "первый пришел - первый ушел", то есть пока один человек получает ответ, другой ждет свою очередь. Хотел сделать так, чтобы ты получал ответ на запрос тогда, когда его создал. Использовал следующую конструкцию:

```
import threading
import time
import random


def worker(number):
    sleep = random.randrange(1, 10)
    time.sleep(sleep)
    print("I am Worker {}, I slept for {} seconds".format(number, sleep))


for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    t.start()

print("All Threads are queued, let's see when they finish!")
```

После добавления данной конструкции ситуация изменилась, но теперь все происходило по принципу "последний пришел - первый ушел". Может кто знает, как сделать так, чтобы получать ответы тогда, когда создал запрос?

Comment: в вашем примере последовательность получения ответа зависит от  `sleep = random.randrange(1, 10)`, а не по принципу "последний пришел - первый ушел"

Comment: это пример того, при помощи чего я пытался получить асинхронные запросы, а принцип  "последний пришел - первый ушел" проявился при тесте всего кода